# Depth first search giving wrong output

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[image: Graph]

I wrote the below code to traverse the above graph using depth first search , the output i am getting is 0 1 3 6 4 5 2 .

I want to check if it is the correct traversal using DFS ,if not , what is the correct traversal . Also , what changes i need to incorporate in my code to bring the right output .

```
public void DFSTraversal()
{

    int v;
    int vFirst = 0;
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
    Boolean[] visited = new Boolean[vert];
    for(int j = 0 ; j < vert ; j++ )
    {
        visited[j] = false;
    }

    // st is a stack
    st.push(vFirst);

    while(!st.isEmpty())
    {
        v = st.peek();
        if(!visited[v])
        {
            System.out.printf("%d " , +v);
            visited[v]=true;
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < vert; i++)
            {
                if ((matrix[v][i] == 1) && (!visited[i]))
                {
                    st.push(i);
                    visited[i] = true;
                    System.out.printf("%d ", +i);
                    v = i;
                }
            }

            st.pop();
    }
```

adjacency metric

```
`0 1 1 0 0 0 0`
`1 0 0 1 1 1 0`
`1 0 0 0 0 0 1`
`0 1 0 0 0 0 1`
`0 1 0 0 0 0 1`
`0 1 0 0 0 0 0`
`0 0 1 1 1 0 0`
```

Comment: Paste your code to some online editor and send the link

Answer (score 0):

From the picture, assuming that a vertex's edges are in increasing order by the node that they point to, the correct output is: 0 1 3 6 2 4 5.

The problem that you are having is that you have sort of mixed a dynamic programming approach with the stack, and an iterative approach with the re-writing `for` loop over all vertices. If a vertex has an edge to another vertex that has a lower index than its own index, then it will not visit the node immediately, and will instead resort to the stack; the last vertex to have unvisited edges' first edge.

You fix this by only using the dynamic programming approach, then looping backwards through the edges, pushing them onto the stack if they are unvisited. This will leave the edge to the lowest-valued vertex on the top of the stack, ready to be visited in the next iteration.

Your depth-first search loop then becomes:

```
while (!st.isEmpty()) {
  int vertex = st.pop();
  if (!visited[vertex]) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", vertex);
    visited[vertex] = true;

    for (int i = numVertices - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (edges[vertex][i] == 1 && !visited[i]) {
        st.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way you only use the single loop (your `while` loop), which keeps popping from the stack. When a vertex is visited, it pushes all of its unvisited and connected vertices onto the stack, in reverse order. This means that the lowest-numbered child of a vertex is the next one to be visited (DFS). If a vertex is visited and is deeper in the stack, it is simply ignored when visited again, as are its child vertices (they will already have been visited too).

This could then quite simply be changed to Bread-First Search by making the stack a queue and adding vertices in increasing order.

Comment: have modified my code as per your comment , the output i am getting is 0 1 3 6 2 . Element 4 and 5 are never pushed into stack .

Comment: `while(!st.isEmpty())
        {
            v = st.pop();
        //    System.out.println("popped " + v);
            if(!visited[v])
            {
                System.out.printf("%d " , +v);
                visited[v]=true;
            }

                for (int i = 0; i < vert; i++) {
                    if ((matrix[v][i] == 1) && (!visited[i])) {
                        //st.pop();
                        st.push(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }`

Answer (score -1):

```
    public void DFSTraversal() {

        int v;
        int vFirst = 0;
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
        Boolean[] visited = new Boolean[vert];
        for (int j = 0; j < vert; j++) {
            visited[j] = false;
        }

        // st is a stack
        st.push(vFirst);

        while (!st.isEmpty()) {
            v = st.pop();
            if (!visited[v]) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", +v);
                visited[v] = true;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < vert; i++) {
                if ((matrix[v][i] == 1) && (!visited[i])) {
                    st.push(i);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

You should print the output as you pop elements from the stack. If you're printing it in the for loop where you're checking all the neighbouring nodes of the current node, it would become Breadth First Search (BFS) not DFS.

EDIT:

Added full code.